# How to change image color with a button, without using 360 different css sheets?

Tags: css, colors

I want to change an image's color. There are multiple colors in the image, so the hue-rotate css filter looks awesome and amazing and exactly like what I want ( http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/ link to hue-rotation example). I would like to be able to change the color of an individual image by clicking a button--it would increase the angle by 1* (or set to zero at 360*), changing the images color slightly.

Although I could make a style sheet for each individual degree, it's incredibly impractical. There are several hundred images on the same page that need to have that effect as well, which means...a LOT of separate style sheets if I don't want them to change together. I haven't been able to find any answers using google.

TL;DR want to rotate the hue of an image using a button in a web browser.

Comment: This is why elements can have *individual* styles applied programmatically: e.g. `jQuery.css(..)` or `elm.style`. (Also, style sheet class rules can be manipulated dynamically these days, should the same styling still need to be uniformly applied over a "class of elements".)

Comment: That would still require 360 stylesheets, though. I would need a style sheet for every possible degree.

Comment: No. It wouldn't. Refer to my first comment again. If it *were* the case that separate style sheets were required to apply any CSS style/value/transformation, then to move an image across the screen would require one stylesheet per location. This is, of course, is impractical and not the case. There is no difference between setting a CSS hue transformation value and setting the position (which is itself a form of a transformation) or background color.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using jquery.

Say your image is:

```
    <img src="yourimage.jpeg" id="myimage"/>
```

and you have a button:

```
    <button id="mybutton">Hue Rotator</button>
```

now in your page you need to include jquery.js in your scripts.

A lil bit of scripting can acheive you the rest.

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            var degree = 0;

            var rotatehue = function(){
                    degree++;
                    if(degree>360)degree=0;
                    $('#myimage').css('-webkit-filter','hue-rotate('+degree+'deg)');
            }

            $('#mybutton').bind('click',function(){
                    window.setInterval(rotatehue,30);
            });

    });
    </script>
```

Now clicking on the button, your image should start rotating hue.